# Cannot add UITextField to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a View Controller, to which I add a Scroll View. Then I add number of UITextFields, dynamically resizing the UIScrollView.contentSize, according to how many text fields the user needs.
So far I have checked and double checked the delegates, the size of the contentSize property, the origin and size of the text fields. I use the following piece of code to do that:

```
-(void)setScrollViewSize
{
    NSLog(@"Rows count: %d", self.rows);
    self.matrixInputScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
    CGSize scrollVieSize;
    if (!self.columns) {
    NSLog(@"Setting scroll view frame row");
    scrollVieSize = CGSizeMake(self.rows * TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH + (self.rows - 1) * TEXT_FIELD_INDENT, TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting scroll view frame rows and columns");
        scrollVieSize = CGSizeMake(self.rows * TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH + (self.rows - 1) * TEXT_FIELD_INDENT, self.columns * TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT + (self.columns - 1) * TEXT_FIELD_INDENT);
    }
    self.matrixInputScrollView.contentSize = scrollVieSize;

     if (!self.columns) {
         for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.rows; ++i) {
             NSLog(@"Text filed adding");
             UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH + TEXT_FIELD_INDENT), 0, TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH, TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT)];
             NSLog(@"uitextfield position ad size: %f %f %f %f", textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
             [self.matrixInputScrollView addSubview:textField];
         }
      }
      else
      {
          for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.rows; ++i) {
             for (NSInteger j = 0; j < self.columns; ++j) {
                  UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH + TEXT_FIELD_INDENT), j * (TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT + TEXT_FIELD_INDENT), TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH, TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT)];
                   [self.matrixInputScrollView addSubview:textField];
            }
         }
      }

    NSLog(@"Before setNeedsDisplay");
    NSLog(@"Scroll view position and size: %f %f %f %f",      self.matrixInputScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.matrixInputScrollView.frame.origin.y,   self.matrixInputScrollView.frame.size.width, self.matrixInputScrollView.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Scroll view content size: %f %f", self.matrixInputScrollView.contentSize.width,    self.matrixInputScrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```

The output of the above sample is as follows:

```
2013-10-16 15:27:30.672 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Rows count: 3
2013-10-16 15:27:30.672 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Setting scroll view frame row
2013-10-16 15:27:30.673 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Text filed adding
2013-10-16 15:27:30.673 RZCalc[2765:a0b] uitextfield position ad size: 0.000000 0.000000 40.000000 30.000000
2013-10-16 15:27:30.674 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Text filed adding
2013-10-16 15:27:30.674 RZCalc[2765:a0b] uitextfield position ad size: 50.000000 0.000000 40.000000 30.000000
2013-10-16 15:27:30.674 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Text filed adding
2013-10-16 15:27:30.675 RZCalc[2765:a0b] uitextfield position ad size: 100.000000 0.000000 40.000000 30.000000
2013-10-16 15:27:30.675 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Before setNeedsDisplay
2013-10-16 15:27:30.676 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Scroll view position and size: 76.000000 42.000000 244.000000 246.000000
2013-10-16 15:27:30.676 RZCalc[2765:a0b] Scroll view content size: 140.000000 30.000000
```

What you see here is the scroll view being created and placed on screen, the content size resized accordingly and 3 textfields created and added to the scroll view with their origins and sizes within the contentSize limits.

The result is the scroll view being displayed on the screen and the textfields are not.

Can you tell if there is something wrong with the above code or do you need more information about it?

Comment: How is the content size resized properly, when you are setting it before you are adding the new row? Look at your last log row: Content Size is only 30 in height and 140 in width and your last textfield is at X:67, Y:42 (out of content size)

Comment: Just a tip for NSLog-ing a CGRect. Use `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(yourframe));`.

Comment: Are you sure they are not displayed. Put some text in the TextFields to be sure.

Comment: Set the background color of the labels to something different than the color of your scrollview to see if they are present.  You are not setting any formatting options for the labels so they may just be transparent views at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, @Putz1103, that was the problem. I set the background color to white and all of the sudden all my text field were there. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer:

Set the background color of the labels to something different than the color of your scrollview to see if they are present. You are not setting any formatting options for the labels so they may just be transparent views at the moment.